# how to filter dataframe using a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i would like to use the following function to filter a dataframa

```py
def isInRadius(position):
    latCheck = False
    lonCheck = False
    if position.lat < 0:
        latCheck = position.lat <= upperLat and position.lat >= lowerLat
    else:
        latCheck = position.lat >= upperLat and position.lat <= lowerLat

    if not latCheck:
        return False

    if position.lon < 0:
        lonCheck = position.lon <= righterLon and position.lon >= lefterLon
    else:
        lonCheck = position.lon >= righterLon and position.lat <= lefterLon

    return latCheck and lonCheck
```

The dataframe has more columns than 'lat' and 'lon' but i would like to filter it by those 2 according to the logic implemented on the function above.

I have try `dataFrame.filter(lambda x: isInRadius(x))` and `dataFrame.filter(isInRadius)` and `dataFrame.filter(lambda x: isInRadius(x.iLoc[0]))` and other approaches but none worked, resulting in the error "TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable"

How should i do it?

On C# i would do

```
var filtered = myCollection.Where(x => isInRadius(x));
```

Comment: what's `lowerLat`, `upperLat`, etc? Can you explain the logic of `isInRadius`?

Comment: `filter` works on index, so it should not work regardless of what syntax you use since the filtering you want is done over the values and not the indexes

Comment: does it really matter? upperLat, lowerLat, righterLon and lefterLon defines a box on the surface of the earth and i wanna know if the position provided is inside it...

Comment: [pd.DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas-dataframe-filter) is used to filter the dataframe based on the index or column header labels.  You need to create a boolean series using your function then use `.loc`.

Comment: Try something like `df[df.apply(lambda x: isInRadius(x), 1)]`

Comment: @pythonic833 worked! pls post as answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `.apply` functionality of pandas dataframes

```
df[df.apply(isInRadius, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use an apply

```
import pandas as pd

df2 =pd.DataFrame({'lookup_id':['a','a','c','c','c'],'val':[1,1,1,1,1]})
print(df2)

  lookup_id  val
0         a    1
1         a    1
2         c    1
3         c    1
4         c    1

# Replace this with whatever your function actually does
def val_is_a(r):
    return r['lookup_id'] =='a'

df2.loc[lambda df : val_is_a(df)]

    lookup_id   val
0   a           1
1   a           1
```